# Displacement causing artifacting on mesh

Tags: displacement

[image: The clipping]

I'm using displacement to achieve this snowy effect but its creating these weird artifacts in the highlighted area, I'm not sure what is causing this or how to fix it.

This is just a subdivided plane

Any help appreciated!

Edit: forgot to specify that he displacement is done using material nodes

Comment: Is this displacement in material nodes or displace modifier?

Comment: It's in the material nodes